# is there a way to look at the code behind an __enter__() function in the python interpreter?

Tags: python

question pretty much says it all.

i'd like to look at the code in this fashion:

```
>>>f = open("x.txt")
>>>print contents of f.__enter__() #<- how can I do this?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. (Other than looking at the Python source code.)

```
>>> f = open("x.txt")
>>> f.__enter__
<built-in method __enter__ of file object at 0x022E4E90>
```

So the implementation of `__enter__` is somewhere inside Python's C code.

It's actually in `Objects/fileobject.c` which you can find [in the Python source tree](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b36cb4602e21/Objects/fileobject.c) [note: I think that's the currently-latest thing on the 2.7 branch; there's probably a better way to link to it] and looking at the code you'll see that actually `f.__enter__` returns `f` itself. Of course that's just what happens in this particular case; other objects' `__enter__` methods will do entirely different things.

In this case, it happens that the `__enter__` method is native code. In others it may be Python code, but you still can't generally see it from inside Python.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.localcontext().__enter__
<bound method _ContextManager.__enter__ of <decimal._ContextManager object at 0x02192B50>>
```

That's Python bytecode rather than native code. You can see the bytecode:

```
import dis
dis.dis(decimal.localcontext().__enter__)
```

but the original Python source code is not guaranteed to be available. But you can try:

```
import inspect
print inspect.getsource(decimal.localcontext().__enter__)
```

which will sometimes do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not from an abritary callable (or any other) object. You can try to find the source code, and there's even [a function in the standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) that can do this in many cases. However, the I/O modules are propably written in C, so you'd have to go and search the [repository](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/).