# does __enter__ typically include a try block?

Tags: python, try-catch

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488971/is-there-a-way-to-look-at-the-code-behind-an-enter-function-in-the-python-i) question yesterday. But now I realize it was the wrong question. Do `__enter__` functions typically contain try blocks?

Comment: Maybe you should ask yet another quesion.  What is your actual aim?  Why do you want to know this?  Some `__enter__()` methods written in Python may contain a try-except-block, but there is no stronger reason for them to contain such a block than for any other method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can if you are prepared to recover from the exception gracefully, but *generally* you would want to allow the exception to bubble upward to the caller (or raise one of your own if that's more appropriate), preventing the `with` block from being entered if something went wrong with the setup.